# psexec get env value in command

Tags: powershell, remote-access, psexec

I've defined environment variable on the TARGET machine and I am trying to run interactive app remotely but this requires RDP session ID. That env variable is correct RDP session ID.
So, how can I access that env variable and execute psexec command?

```
C:\\skripte\\psexec64 \\TARGET -u DOMAIN\USER -p PASSWORD-h -i "Powershell Get-Content env:\id" C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe
```

Comment: does `id:\` work for you?

Comment: You might have to do this in 2 steps, getting the id first.